# offline data issue when navigating to new screen

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have an offline storage with resource name as "testResource" in Screen1. Same resource is used in another Screen2. However when i invoke it as 
ModelService.all('testResource',null,null,false) in Screen2, im not getting data.

I have added it in required resources tab in Screen1 and Screen2. Please help in resolving this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clear the filter applied to that resource? Is it null or simply empty?